# elastic - Filter documents based on field from nested array and retrieve that nested field value

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

Let's suppose I have a document like this:

```js
{
  _source: {
    data: 'hello'
    nested1: [{
      
      nested2: [{
       data1: 'hello',
       important_info: 7
      },
      {
       data1: 'hello1',
       important_info: 8
      }
      ]
      
      }
    ]
  },
  {
      
      nested2: [{

       data1: 'hello3',
       important_info: 4
      },
      {
       data1: 'hello',
       important_info: 7
      }
      ]
      
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and I want to make an aggregation on `important_info` and choose it from first `nested2` object which has `data1` equals with `data`.
It's like the root document should have a field `important_info` and I'm trying to retrieve it from nested array.

Comment: if its possible, then I assume this is only done through scripting https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html

Comment: I've tried with scripting, but didn't succeed